# is the vibration for call setting accessible in android?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1, setting, vibration, android-vibration

Is there a way I can access the system preference for vibration settings?

I have an alarm-like app which I want to inherit the vibration setting from the phone's ring/sound settings. However, I do not know how to programmatically access these settings.

Comment: Do you want to implement Vibration?

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using the AudioManager.  The suggestions I saw around for getRingerMode() do not work for proper vibration setting detection.

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
boolean vibrate = am.shouldVibrate(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER);
```

Wish there was a way to get the actual setting which on my phone has 4 different modes

1. Always
2. Never
3. Only in Silent Mode
4. Not in Silent Mode

Answer (score 0):

To get the settings for the vibration use:
[getVibrateSetting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#getVibrateSetting%28int%29) which may or may not require the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Try first without the permission.